# Implementing a queue in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, c++11

I'm trying to implement a really basic queue (as an array) in my computer science class and want some feedback on my logic/methodology.  the queue is not circular, it just includes the basic functions of enqueue/dequeue (along with the other obvious ones.) Please criticize and give feedback so I can educate myself on the best practices.

I was given this assignment as part of an entry level CS class. I was told not to make a circular queue. So this of course is not an efficient model by any means.. just a rough idea of what queues do.

what the code should do: users can add to the queue by moving forward the last element of the array, and "remove" items (they kinda still float around in memory though. remove isn't a great word) by moving the first element forward.

Class declaration:

```
class queueList
{
private:
    int *list;
    int queueFront;
    int queueRear;
    int maxSize;

public:
    void enqueue(const int &x);
    bool isEmpty();
    bool isFull();
    void dequeue();
    queueList(const int &x);
    int front();
    int back();
};
```

class implementation:

````
queueList::queueList(const int &x)
{
    list = new int[x];
    queueRear = 0;
    queueFront = 0;
    maxSize = x;
}
void queueList::enqueue(const int &x)
{
    if (!isFull())
    {
        list[queueRear] = x;
        //cout << list[queueRear] << endl;
        queueRear++;
    }
}
bool queueList::isEmpty()
{
    return (queueFront == queueRear);
}
bool queueList::isFull()
{
    return (queueRear == maxSize);
}

void queueList::dequeue()
{
    if (!isEmpty())
    {
        list[queueFront] = 0;
        cout << list[queueFront] << endl;
        queueFront++;
    }
}

int queueList::front()
{
    return list[queueFront];
}

int queueList::back()
{
    return list[queueRear];
}
```
````

Comment: Could you add a short explanation for how your code works, and why you made any unorthodox choices if you did?

Comment: @k00lman sure thing, I added a description that added more detail.

Comment: I always worry about these sorts of classes, where they ask you to implement  queues and lists and things.   I get that they are designed to teach low level coding skills, but seem to forget that you should never (99.9999% of the time) write your own, but use the one provided by the library.   Would a carpenters training include how to make wood glue and a saw?

Comment: Why fiddle your own, when its already there and widely available : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue
@Neil maybe not the saw - where they would teach how to use it properly without sawing fingers off - but carpenters glue ... should still be taught

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `std::size_t` for container sizes and indices, not `int`.

```
std::size_t queueFront;
std::size_t queueRear;
std::size_t maxSize;
```

Use meaningful variable names. When I use your constructor, what does "x" mean? Something like `queue_size` is more meaningful. This can also be a `std::size_t`. This also doesn't need to be a reference, since it's likely the same size as a pointer, but feel free to continue passing as reference if you want. You just normally don't see that with primitive types.

```
queueList(std::size_t queue_size);
```

Similarly, pick a meaningful name for your `enqueue` function. Even something like `value` carries more meaning than `x`. This should NOT be a `std::size_t`, since obviously you do want to insert an `int` into your `int` array.

Handle the special case in your constructor where the passed-in size is 0 or less. It won't be less than 0 if you switch to `size_t`, but it can still be 0. Do you want to allow this? How do you manage the memory? Calling `new int[0];` is undefined behavior. Also, use initializer lists when possible for constructors. It prevents variables from being double-assigned and objects from being double-constructed. You won't notice any speedup on this problem, but it's a good habit to get into.

```
queueList::queueList(std::size_t queue_size)
  : list(queue_size > 0 ? new int[queue_size] : nullptr)
  , queueRear(0)
  , queueFront(0)
  , maxSize(queue_size)
{ }
```

Explicitly `delete` your default constructor to avoid ambiguity.

```
queueList() = delete;
```

Your constructor manages a resource (memory allocated with `new`), so you must also declare a destructor that `delete`s the memory. Since you must declare a destructor, you must follow at LEAST the [rule of 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and define a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator. A best practice would be to follow the rule of 5 (same link as rule of 3) and define additionally a move constructor and move assignment operator.

They key with all of these is: what does it mean to create a copy of your queue? What does it mean to move your queue? Most of these questions will have to do with managing the underlying allocated memory.

```
~queueList() { delete[] list }; // destructor
queueList(const queueList& other); // copy constructor
queueList& operator=(const queueList& other); // copy assignment operator
queueList(queueList&& other); // move constructor
queueList& operator=(queueList&& other); // move assignment operator
```

Your queue is currently one-time-use. It can only ever hold `queue_size` (`x` in your code) elements ever. It can't hold more elements than what you initially allocate. The latter is surmountable, but you should make it a goal to allow the queue to grow (or have a policy of throwing some error, or letting the user know through documentation that excess values will be lost). The one-time usability of each data slot is CRIMINAL though. My suggestion is to allow `queueRear` and `queueFront` to wrap around the array using modulo arithmetic as they move to the right.

**dequeue should return a value!!!** This is a huge shock to anyone who will try to use your class. They don't always want to print the value. They likely want to use it in some future calculation. This is easy. However, your current code doesn't even print the current value. It just always overwrites it with 0, then prints 0. This also decouples your class from requiring iostream to work.

Change your dequeue to look like this:

```
int queueList::dequeue()
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        // figure out what to do here.
        // Throw an error? Seems appropriate. 
        // Another option is to return a std::pair<int, bool>,
        // where the second value indicates whether there were
        // any items in the queue
    }
    int retval = list[queueFront++];
    queueFront = queueFront % maxSize; // talking about modulo arithmetic earlier
    return retval;
}
```

Your `isEmpty()` and `isFull()` functions can have their prototypes modified to be `const`, since neither modify the object:

```
bool isEmpty() const
{
    ...
}

bool isFull() const
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you for such a thoughtful reply! My teacher actually asked for the queue not to be circular (which is inefficient and means the queue isn't very functional). With this in mind, do you think the logic is okay for how I'm determining whether my queue is empty or full? If I have a queue of three components and ran it through my dequeue function 3 times, my front and rear would both end with index three. Is the logic ok there?

Comment: The logic there is okay, yes. As long as you and your teacher are both aware that this is a one-time-use operation queue.